# how to use postgres.db.name for multiple databases in kubernetes configMaps

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

So I want to create multiple postgresql databases in the kubernetes deployment.
I tried with the below configMaps configuration but the databases are not being created. I tried to log into the postgres db pod with one of the database names I used in the configMaps but it say's the databse doesn't exist.

method 1:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: hydra-kratos-postgres-config
  labels:
    app: hydra-kratos-db
data:
  postgres.db.user: pguser
  postgres.db.password: secret
  postgres.db.name: 
    - postgredb1
    - postgredb2
    - postgredb3
```

method 2:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: hydra-kratos-postgres-config
  labels:
    app: hydra-kratos-db
data:
  POSTGRES_USER: pguser
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
  POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES:
    - kratos
    - hydra


Would appreciate any suggestions on this. Thank you.
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using official Postgres image - by default it doesn't support multiple databases declaration on init. You could try building your own Postgres image like in [this repo](https://github.com/mrts/docker-postgresql-multiple-databases). If you create k8s deployment based on such image, I think there is a chance that your variable `POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES` could work.

Let me know if you decide to try this.